# I'm trying to call a PHP function inside a echo

Tags: php, database, function

i'm trying to call getMensClothing() function from function.php to header.php

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "khaki";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


function getMensClothing(){
global $conn;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM men_clothing";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<li><a href='#' class='hvr-grow'>". $row['men_clo_items']."      </a></li>";
    }
} 
}
```

header.php file looks like this

```
<?php include 'functions.php'; ?>
<?php
     echo' 
          <div class="col-sm-2"><br>
                <a href="men\'s_clothing.php"><p> <b>Men\'s Clothing</b></p></a>
                <ul>
                '.getMensClothing().'
                </ul>
           </div>'
?>
```

function is called but the items aren't displayed where it has to everything is show at the top of the page . How to display the items inside the div ??

Comment: Use `return` instead of `echo` in a function

Comment: Because you don't return the data in your function. You print them out, so they get printed before.

Comment: I'm amused but also concerned at the fact that many beginners use echo in their functions and think this is a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

Use below Code

```
$html = "";
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $html .= "<li><a href='#' class='hvr-grow'>". $row['men_clo_items']."</a></li>";
    }
} 
return $html;
```

into your function.php file

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

create a class like

```
class support{

//inside goes codes and functions

}
```

while calling into another file.

include it above file then create

```
$a=new support()
$a->functionname();
```

this should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that you use `echo` with parameters, that are evaluated to be printed.
You use concatenation with your arguments to `echo`.
You have one parameter contructed with the concatenation of three arguments.
The result of this concatenation is printed. One of these arguments is the returned value of the `getMensClothing()` function.

During the evaluation of `getMensClothing()` you print some data.
Consequently, the data printed in your function `getMensClothing()` gets printed before the end of the call to `echo` statement in `header.php`.

As other people pointed out, you should reconsider your technique as your code could be more easy to use if you separate the job of retrieving and constructing your data and the job of displaying it. Have a look to [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) for instance.